# How do i make auto-complete work for multiple forms using the same (css) id?

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, jquery-autocomplete

The following code is meant to search through a company list and return top 10 results. It works perfectly fine for a single input form with a single id(css).

When I have a second form in the view with the same id, the auto-complete works only for the first instance where I call the input id="company". For my purpose, I have multiple forms for which i need the same auto-complete to work without having to change the id (company1, company2 etc.)

I do not want to rewrite the script section for every instance of the input form. 
Is there anyway to have the auto complete work for all inputs using the same id?

app/view:

```
 <script>
 $('#company').autocomplete({

     minLength: 2,

     source: '<%= company_path %>',

     focus: function(event, ui) {
         $('#company').val(ui.item.name);
         return false;
     },

     select: function(event, ui) {
         $('#company').val(ui.item.name);
         return false;
     }
 })


        .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )

                .append( "<a>" + item.name + "</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul );
        };

});

</script>

<input type="text" class="span11" id="company" name = "company" >  ***<!--autocomplete works fine-->***

<input type="text" class="span11" id="company" name = "company" >  ***<!--autocomplete does not work in second instance -->***
```

config/routes:

```
match '/company', to: 'search#company_autocomplete'
```

controller/search_controller

```
  def company_autocomplete
  if params[:term]
    if params[:term].length>1
    @companies_autocomplete = Company.select(:name).where( 'name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:term]}%").first(10)

    end
  end

   render :json => @companies_autocomplete.to_json 

  end
```

Comment: Sigh, that is because ID's are unique, and you can't have the same ID twice in the same document, there are no fixes other than writing valid code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hacky, but instead of writing `$("#company")`, you can write `$("*[id=company]")`.

Answer (score 1):

IDs need to be unique. Generally if you need to apply the same thing to two different items, you should use a class.

```
<input type="text" class="span11 company" id="company1" name = "company" >

<input type="text" class="span11 company" id="company2" name = "company" >
```

Then your JS selectors can just use periods instead of #

```
$('.company').autocomplete({

     minLength: 2,

     source: '<%= company_path %>',

     focus: function(event, ui) {
         $('.company').val(ui.item.name);
         return false;
     },

     select: function(event, ui) {
         $('.company').val(ui.item.name);
         return false;
     }
 })
```